# c# built exe file has 0 file size but only in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ilmerge

I'm not very familiar with c# as in how the project and solution properties work. I inherited a c# project and needed to modify it. after modifying in debug mode and testing I changed the mode to release, and tried to build but it failed because ILMerge.exe needed .NET Framework 3.5.

I followed [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/127492-how-to-enable-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-10-offline) guide to install .NET Framework 3.5 offline as I have no internet access on the system that I code on. I skipped step 3 because I did not understand it and also because I think it is for installing it on multiple pcs. anyway after doing these things, the project did build successfully on release mode(not really) but the exe file size is zero. it seems like that ILMerge did not work correctly and failed to merge. so what should I do?

Comment: IlMerge has a log commandline option. You should have a look at the logs.

Comment: Check the merge log to see why it cannot be merged.